# Is there a naming convention how to call the file where authors will be listed?

Tags: naming-conventions

I remember that Evil Martians (known Russian developers team) tried popularize some approach for this aim. But can't find anything about this now.

Comment: contributors.md?

Comment: Maybe. Their convention was different.

Comment: Maybe ask them directly on twitter or something?

Comment: I want just choose most popular approach. contributors.md is a standart?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I don't even know what you're asking about (authors? what authors?)

Comment: Any project. No matter. Authors of projects.

Comment: What i looked for was http://humanstxt.org/ )

Comment: First time I hear of this :)

Comment: @IldarMeyker rather interesting (as long as it's facultative), put it as an answer, to give it more visibility. That's just for the authors of web sites though, if that's what you meant you should also edit the question.